# Using Jquery.hammer and Hammer 2.0.2 with RequireJS

Tags: jquery, requirejs, require, hammer.js

Just updated to Hammer 2.0.2 and added the [jquery.hammer plugin](https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js) and I'm having trouble requiring it in a project.

Currently, I am just getting '*Uncaught ReferenceError: Hammer is not defined*'

When I try to just require Hammer, I do not have access to Hammer in the console.

Here is the important stuff in my require config.

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    '$': '../components/jquery/jquery',
    'jquery': '../components/jquery/jquery',
    'hammer': '../components/hammerjs/hammer',
    'jquery-hammer': '../components/jquery-hammer/jquery.hammer'
  },
  shim: {
    $: {
      exports: '$'
    },
    jquery: {
      exports: '$'
    },
    'hammer': {
      exports: 'Hammer'
    },
    'jquery-hammer': {
      deps:['$','hammer']
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Same issue for me. I guess that "Hammer" is not correctly exported. I used to do `Hammer = require("Hammer");` in last version in my require callback to access it. But now it is not found in the plugin. May be try to load it after ?

Answer (score 0):

Worked this way for me, remove jquery-hammer from your paths and shim

```
require(["Hammer", "jquery"], function(){
Hammer = require("Hammer");
jQuery = require("jquery");

  require([
        "../components/jquery-hammer/jquery.hammer", //or the path of your jquery.hammer
        //Any other lib
        ], function(){
            //your previous init code
        }
});
```

What is does is forcing the jQuery and Hammer variable to be set before calling jquery.hammer plugin

Answer (score 0):

1. Install **npm i hammerjs**
2. Add to package.json --->
   **"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
   "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
   "types": [ "hammerjs",
   "jasmine",
   "jasminewd2",
   "node",
   "q",
   "selenium-webdriver" ]**
3. add **import 'hammerjs';** to **main.ts** file
4. If you still have problems use:
   **npm --force**
   **npm install**